# Подключил ol7_optional_latest и не меняется статус на ENABLED

Tags: linux

Здравствуйте.

добавил репозиторий

```
[ol7_optional_latest]
name=Oracle Linux $releasever Optional Latest ($basearch)
baseurl=http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/optional/latest/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
after execute
```

выполнил команды обновления YUM

```
yum clean all
yum --enablerepo=ol7_optional_latest clean metadata
```

проверяю статус репозитория и DISABLED

```
ol7_optional_latest/x86_64    Oracle Linux 7Server Optional Latest (x86_64)                                                         disabled
```

Как решить проблему и перевести его в ENABLED?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

после

```
yum clean all
```

выполняем

```
yum-config-manager --enable ol7_optional_latest
```

проверяем результат

```
yum repolist all


!ol7_optional_latest/x86_64    Oracle Linux 7Server Optional Latest (x86_64)                                                        enabled: 12,831+3,515
```